# How can I use pipe function in R to command GNUPlot?

Tags: r, plot, latex, pipe, gnuplot

How can I use pipe() in R to draw the following by calling gnuplot through that pipe?

```
set terminal latex
set output "eg1.tex"
plot [-3.14:3.14] sin(x)
```

I can't figure out how to use pipes in R.

Comment: why can't you just write those commands to a temp file and use `system`?

Comment: You can always just do `system('echo \'set terminal latex; set output "eg1.tex"; plot [-3.14:3.14] sin(x)\' | gnuplot')`

Comment: @hrbrmstr I can but I want to know how to use pipes. Thanks for suggestions though that's not what I meant in my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do the same thing that `system` is doing with `pipe`:

```
# set up pipe for writing 
gp <- pipe('gnuplot','w')

# send some data to it
cat('set terminal latex; set output "eg1.tex"; plot [-3.14:3.14] sin(x)',
    file=gp)

# close the connection
close(gp)
```

You should see `eg1.tex` in the current working directory.

It will work with newlines as well:

```
cat('set terminal latex
set output "eg1.tex"
plot [-3.14:3.14] sin(x)',
    file=gp)
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. In order to get it working I had remove **;** otherwise I couldn't see the output (mac os x).